# Mongodb Java 3.4 - get fields from embedded document

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I can't retrieve the address fields from my embedded document. I haven't seen any solutions for the 3.4 MongoDB driver.

```
System.out.println("Selecting Person ");

MongoCollection<Document> collection = mdb.getCollection("Person");
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();

try {           
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document temp_person_doc=cursor.next();
        Document temp_address_doc=temp_person_doc.get("address");   
        String houseNo=temp_address_doc.getString("houseNo");       
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Here is the document structure.

```
{
    "_id" : "5aae9920982f271ba4b08735",
    "firstName" : "homer",
    "surname" : "simpson",
    "address" : {
        "houseNo" : 742,
        "address" : "evergreen terrace",
        "city" : "springfield",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see two issues with your code:

1. This will not return a document

   ```
   Document temp_address_doc=temp_person_doc.get("address");
   ```
2. The `houseNo` attribute is an `Integer` not a `String`

   ```
   String houseNo=temp_address_doc.getString("houseNo");
   ```

If you just change `get("address")` to `get("address", Document.class)` then you'll be on the right track.

For example:

```
Document temp_person_doc = cursor.next();

// get the sub document _as a_ Document
Document temp_address_doc = temp_person_doc.get("address", Document.class);

// get the houseNo attribute (which is an integer) from the sub document
Integer houseNo = temp_address_doc.getInteger("houseNo");
// get the address attribute (which is a string) from the sub document
String address = temp_address_doc.getString("address");

// prints 742
System.out.println(houseNo);    
// prints evergreen terrace
System.out.println(address);
```

Key points to note:

- You must read the sub document as a `Document`
- You must read the `houseNo` attribute as an `Integer`